# Sharepoint 2010 deployment problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a VS2010 solution with two projects, MyProject.Silverlight and MyProject.Sharepoint. I want to automatically deploy the .xap silverlight ouput into the VirtualDirectories\80\wpresources folder.

The sharepoint project has a single module which references the silverlight output xap file using "project output references". The sharepoint project is configured with the "WebApplication" assembly deployment target.

If I set the .xap deployment type to anything other than ClassResource, the file ends up where I would expect it to be. However, if I choose ClassResource (which is the correct one, right?), I cannot see it being deployd anywhere.

This seems to only be the case when I use the "project output references" option. If I manually add the xap file as an existing item and choose deployment type ClassResource, it ends up in the correct folder.

Any clues?

Comment: you may try on [sharepoint.se]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the XAP to be deployed at `VirtualDirectories\80\wpresources`, why would you choose `ClassResources` ?

The resources get embedded within the assembly which probably you are not looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543289.aspx

Comment: I followed the instructions on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14521/sharepoint-2010-wpresources-for-bin-web-application-deployment, but they didn't work. As I said, if i do the same thing with a constant resource instead of the project output references, then it works. I am not editing any xml-files.